# Is this a valid way to implement a callback with return data?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I need a simple utility class which can handle loading XML for an `AIR` desktop project and want to ask if this approach is valid or if there is a better way to do this. (full code below - example is using "text" not "xml")

This class takes a request from another object with the following params:

```
             public function loadTextFile(filename:String, 
                                         directory:File, 
                                              call:Function):void
```

After completing the task the class packs the result in an `Object` instance and calls the callback function.

```
              var obj:Object = getResultObject(true, "text", fileContents);
              callback(obj);
```

I am wondering specifically if using the `Object` in this way (setting properties on it on the fly is valid/supported.

*(The reason I need this is irrelevant but it is because I've inherited a project which A. has 20+ classes each loading XML in their own way using `URLRequest`, and B. each of those classes assumes the XML file is relative to the application directory)*

---

```
         public function loadTextFile(filename:String, 
                                     directory:File, 
                                call:Function):void
        {   
            callback = call;
            var theFile:File = directory.resolvePath(filename);
            if (! theFile.exists){
                var obj:Object = getResultObject(false, "text");
                callback(obj);
            } else {

                var fileStreamObj:FileStream = new FileStream();
                fileStreamObj.openAsync(theFile,FileMode.READ);

                var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
                fileStream.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, fileComplete );
                fileStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

                fileStream.openAsync( theFile, FileMode.READ );
            }
        }

        private function fileComplete( event : Event ):void
        {
            var fileStream:FileStream  = event.target as FileStream;
            fileStream.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, fileComplete );
            fileStream.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

            var fileContents:String = fileStream.readMultiByte( fileStream.bytesAvailable, ISO_CS );
            fileStream.close();
        }

        private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void 
        {   
            var fileStream:FileStream  = event.target as FileStream;
            fileStream.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, fileComplete );
            fileStream.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

            var obj:Object = getResultObject(false, "text");
            callback(obj);
        }

        private function getResultObject(result:Boolean, type:String, data:*= null):Object
        {
            var obj:Object = new Object;
            obj["result"] = result;

            switch(type) {
                case "text":
                    obj["text"] = data;
                    break;

                default:

                    break;
            }
                return obj;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we start: `Function` is different to `function`. A `Function` is the OO representation of a complied `function`, a `function` can be called directly using it's reference name, a `Function` cannot. (note the deliberate use of capitalization for the difference between the two)

Your current implementation would work if you changed how you treated the `Function` object. You cant call the `function` represented by the `Function` object in the same way you'd call the regular `function` you need to use the `Function.apply()` method.

```
var callback:Function = call;
        var theFile:File = directory.resolvePath(filename);
        if (! theFile.exists){
            var obj:Object = getResultObject(false, "text");
            callback.apply(null,[obj]);
        }
```

The `apply()` method accepts two parameters, the first is the object to operate on, if null is passed it uses the default object associated with the `Function`, the second is an array of arguments to pass to the root `function`. This is how the standard `EventDispatcher.addEventListener()` and `callLater()` architecture works behind the scenes as well

Comment: Hey - thanks! I'm passing in a `Function` from a class instance so it is a `Bound Method` (I believe) so my calling it: `callback(obj)` is working. You are referring to passing the function (`String`) name I think, yes? With `callback.apply(null,[obj]);` (a null target) if there are multiple classes with a `function` of the same name, won't that cause a conflict? Alternately, if I pass in an object ref with a callback `function` name, My utility class will need to import the callee class in order to store the ref – or can I just store it as an instance as 'Object'?

Comment: Oh - is it cool to pack the `Object` class like that – defining properties on the fly? It is very different from other languages I have used.

Comment: Your callback() won't work unless it's actually a function. It appears you assign the reference of call to callback and call is a Function, requiring the apply method

Comment: Most languages I've encounter allow you to create an array with content using [...]